# Constant 500 Internal Server Errors on WordPress Site

Tags: wordpress

There is no consistency to when the errors happen, and within about a minute or two a refresh of the page "fixes" the issue. But then of course, it will happen again with time. Deleting the `.htaccess` file causes a 404 error and will not regenerate the file. I know that this is usually caused by bad plugins/themes, however the issue doesn't last long enough/is consistent enough to be able to test by disabling individual plugins.

The server error log says `Cannot allocate memory`

Is this a php memory limit issue? But then why does this happen so inconsistently?

Comment: Is this a dedicated server / VPS that you control, or shared hosting? It could mean the entire server is low on memory -- and if using shared hosting, it could be caused by another site on the same server, and would be a problem the hosting company should fix.

Comment: I control the server

Comment: And there are other sites on it^

Comment: Have you tried setting the wp_memory_limit and wp_max_memory constants in your wp-config? Set them to 512M or more.

Answer (score 0):

It could indeed be a php memory issue, which can be resolved by increasing `memory limit` in the `php.ini` file. This often happens when a site has a lot of traffic and the amount of memory available is not enough to handle it.

You could also try and raise the wordpress memory limit defined in `/wp-includes/default-constants.php`

If your site is not having a lot of traffic, but this still happens, it could mean your site is running somming processes in the background. Something like a `crobjob` perhaps?

There is no definitive answer to your question, since there can be a lot of different things causing your issue.

But even after increasing your `memory limit`, it is wise to spend some time to figure out what your site does that needs that amout of memory.